# How to use boost optional in an API without exposing all of boost

Tags: c++, api, boost

I would like to return a boost::optional from a method on a library API I am writing. I would like to have a nice migration to std::optional later on.

Is there a clean way to wrap it without exposing all of boost through my API. (I don't want my users to be locked to my boost version)

How can I wrap boost optional (and similarly boost variant)?

These are all header only libraries as far as I know.

Comment: You could roll your your own version of it then switch to `std::optional` later on if you really don't want to pull in the boost libraries.

Comment: Rolling my own is always an option, I guess.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/martinmoene/optional-lite) is a header only version of it on github that might be worth a look.

Comment: Do you really need all features of `boost::optional` in your API? For example, special I/O, move support, special functions like `get_pointer` or `make_optional`? Or do you just need a somewhat glorified and thinly wrapped `template<class T> struct S { T t; bool has_value; }`?